# "shape mismatch" error using numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to generate a random array of 0s and 1s, and I am getting the error: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape. The error seems to be occurring in the line `randints = np.random.binomial(1,p,(n,n))`. Here is the function:

```
import numpy as np

def rand(n,p):
    '''Generates a random array subject to parameters p and N.'''

    # Create an array using a random binomial with one trial and specified
    # parameters.
    randints = np.random.binomial(1,p,(n,n))

    # Use nested while loops to go through each element of the array
    # and assign True to 1 and False to 0.
    i = 0
    j = 0
    rand = np.empty(shape = (n,n),dtype = bool)
    while i < n:
        while j < n:
            if randints[i][j] == 0:
                rand[i][j] = False
            if randints[i][j] == 1:
                rand[i][j] = True
            j = j+1
        i = i +1
        j = 0

    # Return the new array.
    return rand

print rand
```

When I run it by itself, it returns `<function rand at 0x1d00170>`. What does this mean? How should I convert it to an array that can be worked with in other functions?

Comment: What versions of python and numpy are you running? Your code as posted above only has a misindentation in the `i = i +1`...

Comment: The reason it prints `<function rand at 0x1d00170>` when you run this program is because your line `print rand` is printing out the function object. You need to call the function instead. Try: `print rand(4,2)` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needn't go through all of that,

```
 randints = np.random.binomial(1,p,(n,n))
```

produces your array of `0` and `1` values,

```
 rand_true_false = randints == 1
```

will produce another array, just with the `1`s replaced with `True` and `0`s with `False`.

Comment: Another way to convert to True/False is `randints.astype(bool)`

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the answer by @danodonovan is the most Pythonic, but if you really want something more similar to your looping code. Here is an example that fixes the name conflicts and loops more simply.

```
import numpy as np

def my_rand(n,p):
    '''Generates a random array subject to parameters p and N.'''

    # Create an array using a random binomial with one trial and specified
    # parameters.

    randInts = np.random.binomial(1,p,(n,n))

    # Use nested while loops to go through each element of the array
    # and assign True to 1 and False to 0.

    randBool = np.empty(shape = (n,n),dtype = bool)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
             if randInts[i][j] == 0:
                randBool[i][j] = False
             else:
                randBool[i][j] = True

    return randBool


newRand = my_rand(5,0.3)
print(newRand)
```

Comment: Small meta-note: saying "the answer above" may not always be true as other answers are added. It's better to reference the answer by the poster, i.e. "the answer by @danodonovan". Also, it looks like your return statement should be indented into the function.